# searching for a metric, which doesn‘t meterable uniformly on compacts in probability

Tags: probability, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples, uniform-convergence, stochastic-analysis

it is well known, that
$d(X,Y) := \mathbb{E} [ \sup_{t \in [0,T]} |X_t - Y_t | \land 1 ]$ describes a metric and satisfies
$X^n \rightarrow^{ucp} X$ $\iff$ $d(X^n,X) \rightarrow 0$ („meterable“)

Does someone know a metric d, where the second equivalency / statement doesn‘t hold. As a hint: $d$ must be chosen, so that there is a sequence $X^n$ with $d(X^n,X) \rightarrow 0$, but $X^n$ doesn‘t convergent ucp.

Definition ucp: $X^n_t \rightarrow^{ucp} X_t$ if $\sup_{t \in [0,T]} |X^n_t - X| \rightarrow^{n \rightarrow \infty} 0$ in probability

Comment: What does "ucp" mean? Also, you can write `\mathop{\to}\limits^{\mathsf{ucp}}` to have a nicer format: $\mathop{\to}\limits^{\mathsf{ucp}}$. There is also `\xrightarrow{\mathsf{ucp}}` which looks like $\xrightarrow{\mathsf{ucp}}.$ Of course, this is a matter of taste and how much you'd be willing to type.

Comment: What about something like $\tilde d(X,Y):=\Bbb E\left[\int_0^T\left(|X_t-Y_t|\wedge 1\right)\,dt\right]$?

Comment: hey john, thank you! should work with $H_n$ found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3063168/pointwise-convergence-for-predictable-processes-implies-ucp-convergence